# compare the current value of a column to the previous value in pandas dataframe and save the result to other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, which have values like

```
    Date     Col1  col2
    20000101 0.5   0
    20000102 0.5   0.5
    20000103 0     0.25
    20000104 0.5   0.5
```

required output

```
    Date     Col1  col2  col1_1 col2_2
    20000101  0.5  0     Buy    NA
    20000102  0.5  0.5   Hold   Buy
    20000103  0    0.25  Sell     Sell
    20000104  0.5  0.5   Buy    Buy
```

Using the logic, if the current weight is higher than the previous one, then insert 'Buy', in case of no change, then 'Hold', or if lower than the previous one, then insert 'Sell'

I have used the logic

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if i == 1:
        df.loc[0, 'col1'] = 0
    c = df.loc[i, 'col1']
    p = df.loc[i-1, 'col1']

    if c == p:
        df.loc[i, 'col1_1'] = 'Hold'
    elif c > p:
        df.loc[i, 'col1_1'] = 'Buy'
    elif c < p:
        df.loc[i, 'col1_1'] = 'Sell'
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'col1'] = 'NA'
```

Using this, i'm not getting the desired output.

Comment: Shouldn't the third row in `col1_1` be `Sell`?

Comment: Why is first row of `col1_1` Buy, but first row of `col2_2` NA?

Comment: @because initially, i assume that in starting we start from 0\

Comment: I would avoid filling the first row, because in line of that logic `col2_2` should be `hold` since its equal to `0`. Keep it `NA` if you ask me, see my answer

Comment: As per the logic asked, it should be NA in case of initially 0, else Buy

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple conditions, we use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). To compare previous row with current row we use [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html). And because you want to apply the same logic on multiple columns, we define a function to avoid code duplication:

```
def insert_logic(dataframe, col):

    m1 = dataframe[col] > dataframe[col].shift()
    m2 = dataframe[col].eq(dataframe[col].shift())
    m3 = dataframe[col] < dataframe[col].shift()

    df[f'{col}_{col[-1:]}'] = np.select([m1,m2,m3], ['Buy', 'Hold', 'Sell'], default='NA')
```

```
insert_logic(df, 'Col1')
insert_logic(df, 'col2')

       Date  Col1  col2 Col1_1 col2_2
0  20000101   0.5  0.00     NA     NA
1  20000102   0.5  0.50   Hold    Buy
2  20000103   0.0  0.25   Sell   Sell
3  20000104   0.5  0.50    Buy    Buy
```

**Note**: we have `NA` in both columns first rows since there's no previous row to compare with.